# Gradual increasing CPU usage with noble.on('discover') event in Node.js on Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a set of Raspberry Pi Zero Ws running a Node.js application which requires the Noble package in its most basic functional configuration. The described configuration includes initializing Bluetooth low energy scanning and a noble.on('discover') event callback function that filters relevant peripherals and logs the relevant peripheral.

An experiment was set up to monitor the stability of the application over time:

- Between 10-20 iBeacons were configured and turned on in the vicinity of 
  a set of Raspberry Pi Zero Ws all running with the same config.
- CPU and Memory usage for each device was logged over a period of 24 hours.

The results were as follows for the set of Raspberry Pi Zero Ws:

- At the beginning of the experiment, when starting the application, the 
  CPU usage and memory required to run the application was between 20-30% 
  and 9% respectively.
- Over the course of the experiment the CPU usage and 
  memory required to run the application gradually increased from between 
  20-30% and 9% respectively to between 90-100% and 14% respectively.

I'm looking for insight into why this may be happening or if anyone has found a solution to this issue?

The Raspberry Pi Zero W config for the experiment was as follows:

- Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27
- Node.js 8.12.0
- Noble 1.9.1